# Dante server unknown socks version

Tags: proxy, ubuntu-16.04, socks

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Dante-server 1.4

Getting troubles after dante server update. Every connection blocks with error

```
 error after reading 1 byte in  0 seconds: unknown SOCKS version 22 in client request
```

config file:

```
   logoutput: /var/log/danted.log
    debug: 2

    internal: eth0 port = 1080
    external: eth0

    socksmethod: none
    clientmethod: none


    client pass{
           from: 91.238.80.151/32 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
           log: error connect
           socksmethod: none
    }


socks pass{
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        command: bind connect udpassociate
        log: error
```

}

log output:

```
ru_msgsnd  : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_msgrcv  : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nsignals: 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nvcsw   : 4                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nivcsw  : 0                                                                                                                                   
Feb 17 09:41:23 (1487313683.454413) sockd[3012]: debug: removechild(): pid = 3115                                                                  
Feb 17 09:41:23 (1487313683.454418) sockd[3012]: debug: SIGCHLD ]: finished processing signal 17                                                   
Feb 17 09:41:23 (1487313683.454422) sockd[3012]: debug: main(): selectn() returned -1 (Interrupted system call)                                    
Feb 17 09:41:23 (1487313683.454428) sockd[3012]: debug: calling select().  Free negc: 96, reqc: 16, ioc: 32                                        
Feb 17 09:41:23 (1487313683.454444) sockd[3012]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 58, rset = 0x276e630 (7, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 57, ), bufrset = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset =
 (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942756) sockd[3012]: debug: post-select returned 1 (errno: no system error) nfds = 58, rset = 0x276e630 (7, ), bufrset 
= (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                   
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942857) sockd[3012]: debug: main(): selectn() returned 1 (no system error)                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942901) sockd[3012]: debug: accepted tcp client 91.238.80.152.25327 on address 192.168.1.66.1080, fd 7                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942910) sockd[3012]: debug: sending client 91.238.80.152.25327 to negotiate-child (pid 3116 with 96 slots free)        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942916) sockd[3012]: debug: send_client(): buflen = 0                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942925) sockd[3012]: debug: send_client(): sending fd 0 (laddr: 192.168.1.66.1080, raddr: 91.238.80.152.25327, protocol
: tcp) on fd 21 ...                                                                                                                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942971) sockd[3012]: debug: childcheck(): current # of free negotiate-child slots is 95, configured minimum is 96: need
 to add more negotiate-children                                                                                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942993) sockd[3012]: debug: addchild(): type is negotiate-child                                                        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943009) sockd[3012]: debug: setnonblocking(): fd 56: pipe between moter and child                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943018) sockd[3012]: debug: setnonblocking(): fd 58: pipe between moter and child                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943024) sockd[3012]: debug: setnonblocking(): fd 18: pipe between moter and child                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943029) sockd[3012]: debug: setnonblocking(): fd 54: pipe between moter and child                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943036) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_priv(): switching privilege 6 on                                                     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.942997) sockd[3116]: debug: post-select returned 1 (errno: no system error) nfds = 8, rset = 0x2774660 (0, ), bufrset =
 0x2776670 (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943042) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_setugid(): old uid/gid: 1002/1003, new: 0/0                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943092) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_priv(): switching privilege 6 off                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943100) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_setugid(): old uid/gid: 0/0, new: 1002/1003                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943109) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_priv(): switching privilege 6 on                                                     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943113) sockd[3116]: debug: recv_negotiate(): received fd 10 (laddr: 192.168.1.66.1080, raddr: 91.238.80.152.25327, pro
tocol: tcp) ...                                                                                                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943114) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_setugid(): old uid/gid: 1002/1003, new: 0/0                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943137) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_priv(): switching privilege 6 off                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943137) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): 91.238.80.152.25327 -> 192.168.1.66.1080, clientauth N/A, srcauth notset, co
mmand accept, fd 10 from 91.238.80.152.25327, accepted on 192.168.1.66.1080                                                                        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943144) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_setugid(): old uid/gid: 0/0, new: 1002/1003                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943152) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): trying to match against client-rule-rule #1, verdict = pass                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943158) sockd[3012]: debug: addchild(): highest fd in use at the moment: 58                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943168) sockd[3116]: debug: addrmatch(): matching ruleaddress IPv4 address 192.168.1.1/32 port range 1 - 65535 against 
IPv4 address 91.238.80.152.25327 for protocol tcp, without alias                                                                                   
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943181) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): trying to match against client-rule-rule #2, verdict = pass                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943189) sockd[3116]: debug: addrmatch(): matching ruleaddress IPv4 address 91.238.80.152/32 port range 1 - 65535 agains
t IPv4 address 91.238.80.152.25327 for protocol tcp, without alias                                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943198) sockd[3116]: debug: addrmatch(): matching ruleaddress IPv4 address 0.0.0.0/0 against IPv4 address 192.168.1.66.
1080 for protocol tcp, without alias                                                                                                               
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943205) sockd[3116]: debug: methodisset(): checking if method notset is set in the list (1) "none"                     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943212) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): no match yet for method none, command accept                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943216) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): changing authmethod from -1 to 0                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943223) sockd[3116]: debug: methodisset(): checking if method none is set in the list (1) "none"                       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943231) sockd[3116]: debug: accesscheck(): method: none, 91.238.80.152.25327 -> 192.168.1.66.1080                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943238) sockd[3116]: debug: methodisset(): checking if method none is set in the list (0) ""                           
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943242) sockd[3116]: debug: methodisset(): checking if method none is set in the list (0) ""                           
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943248) sockd[3116]: debug: accesscheck(): authentication matched                                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943255) sockd[3116]: debug: rulespermit(): rule matched: 2 (client-rule), verdict pass                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943262) sockd[3116]: debug: setconfsockoptions(): going through options, looking for tcp socket options for fd 10 (in: 
10) on the internal side                                                                                                                           
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943269) sockd[3116]: debug: setconfsockoptions(): going through global array with 0 options, looking for globals matchi
ng 6 (post-establishment or any time)                                                                                                              
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943276) sockd[3116]: debug: setconfsockoptions(): going through local array with 0 options, looking for locals matching
 6                                                                                                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943288) sockd[3116]: debug: shmem_userule(): cinfo: 91.238.80.152.25327                                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943295) sockd[3116]: debug: shmem_userule(): shmids in client-rule #2: bw_shmid 0 ((nil)), mstats_shmid 0 ((nil)), ss_s
hmid 0 ((nil))                                                                                                                                     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943310) sockd[3116]: info: pass(2): tcp/accept [: 91.238.80.152.25327 192.168.1.66.1080                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943325) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_allocbuffer(): fd 10, stype = 1                                                      
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943442) sockd[3116]: debug: recvmsgn(): recvmsg() on fd 0 failed, received -1 bytes: Resource temporarily unavailable  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943450) sockd[3116]: debug: recv_negotiate(): recvmsg() from mother returned -1 after having received 1 new clients (0 
failed/blocked clients).  errno = 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable)                                                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943466) sockd[3116]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 11, rset = 0x2774660 (0, 7, 10, ), bufrset = 0x2776670 (10, ), buffwset 
= (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 30.999999000s                                                                              
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943476) sockd[3116]: debug: post-select returned 1 (errno: no system error) nfds = 11, rset = 0x2774660 (10, ), bufrset
 = 0x2776670 (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 30.999999000s                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943484) sockd[3116]: debug: recv_clientrequest(): fd 10, client 91.238.80.152.25327, state->complete: 0, read so far: 0
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943449) sockd[3124]: debug: postconfigloadinit(): I am a negotiate-child                                               
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943495) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_recvfrom(): fd 10, len 1, flags 0                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943517) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_getfrombuffer(): fd = 10, get up to 1 decoded byte from read buffer which currently h
as 0 decoded, 0 encoded.  Flags = 0                                                                                                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943524) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_freeinbuffer(): fd 10, which 0, free: 288                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943529) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_freeinbuffer(): fd 10, which 0, free: 288                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943524) sockd[3124]: debug: sockd_setcpusettings(): old cpu scheduling policy/priority: other/0, new: other/0          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943540) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_recvfrom(): read 207/288 bytes from socket, fd 10, errno = 0 (no system error)       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943548) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_freeinbuffer(): fd 10, which 0, free: 288                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943554) sockd[3124]: debug: negotiate_postconfigload()                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943553) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_addtobuffer(): fd = 10, add 206 unencoded bytes to read buffer which currently has 0 
unencoded, 0 encoded.  Last bytes to add: 0x1, 0x1.  Data will be added after byte 0x0 which is at offset -1                                       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943568) sockd[3116]: debug: run_negotiate(): recv_clientrequest() from client 91.238.80.152.25327 returned 1, errno is 
0 (no error)                                                                                                                                       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943582) sockd[3116]: info: block(2): tcp/accept ]: 91.238.80.152.25327 192.168.1.66.1080: error after reading 1 byte in
 0 seconds: unknown SOCKS version 22 in client request                                                                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943589) sockd[3116]: debug: delete_negotiate(): forwardedtomother: 0                                                   
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943599) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_sendto(): fd 7, len 1, flags 0, to = NULL                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943610) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_freebuffer(): fd 10                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943615) sockd[3116]: debug: socks_freebuffer(): freeing buffer with data (206/0, 0/0)                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943644) sockd[3116]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 8, rset = 0x2774660 (0, 7, ), bufrset = 0x2776670 (), buffwset = (nil) (
), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.943677) sockd[3124]: debug: addchild(): I am a new negotiate-child with data-pipe 0 and ack-pipe 7                     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944159) sockd[3012]: debug: addchild(): created new negotiate-child with pid 3124, data-pipe 18 and ack-pipe 56.  Minim
um rcvbuf: 23128, set: 46256 and 46256.  Minimum sndbuf: 2220288, set: 4440576 and 4440576                                                         
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944174) sockd[3012]: debug: childcheck(): added child, pid 3124                                                        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944210) sockd[3012]: debug: calling select().  Free negc: 191, reqc: 16, ioc: 32                                       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944258) sockd[3012]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 58, rset = 0x276e630 (7, 10, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 57, ), bufrset = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) ()
, wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944299) sockd[3012]: debug: post-select returned 1 (errno: no system error) nfds = 58, rset = 0x276e630 (57, ), bufrset
 = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944307) sockd[3012]: debug: main(): selectn() returned 1 (no system error)                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944325) sockd[3012]: debug: socks_recvfrom(): fd 57, len 1, flags 0                                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944337) sockd[3012]: debug: handlechildcommand(): command 1 from negotiate-child 3116                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944343) sockd[3012]: debug: handlechildcommand(): negotiate-child 3116 has freed a TCP slot, now has 96 slots free     
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944350) sockd[3012]: debug: childcheck(): counted 96 free negotiate-child slots.  Removing pid 3116 which has handled 1
 client during 97s                                                                                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944357) sockd[3012]: debug: closechild(): pid = 3116, isnormalexit = 1                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944375) sockd[3116]: debug: post-select returned 1 (errno: no system error) nfds = 8, rset = 0x2774660 (7, ), bufrset =
 0x2776670 (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944376) sockd[3012]: debug: calling select().  Free negc: 96, reqc: 16, ioc: 32                                        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944389) sockd[3116]: debug: run_negotiate(): mother telling us to exit normally when done                              
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944401) sockd[3116]: debug: sockdexit(): insignal = 0                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944408) sockd[3116]: debug: negotiate-child: shutting down                                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944411) sockd[3012]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 57, rset = 0x276e630 (7, 10, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, ), bufrset = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset =
 (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                                                          
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944477) sockd[3124]: debug: sockd_print_child_ready_message(): I'm negotiate-child and ready to serve with 65525 free f
ds and 96 free slots                                                                                                                               
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944533) sockd[3124]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 8, rset = 0x2774660 (0, 7, ), bufrset = 0x2776670 (), buffwset = (nil) (
), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                                                                 
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944646) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_pushsignal(): pushed signal 17 from pid 3116.  Number of signals on the stack is now 
1                                                                                                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944675) sockd[3012]: debug: post-select returned -1 (errno: Interrupted system call) nfds = 57, rset = 0x276e630 (7, 10
, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, ), bu
frset = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset = (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0                                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944683) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_handledsignals(): signal #1 on the stack is signal 17                                
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944688) sockd[3012]: debug: sockd_handledsignals(): signals left on the stack after popping signal 17: 0               
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944694) sockd[3012]: debug: SIGCHLD [: processing signal 17                                                            
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944710) sockd[3012]: debug: sigchld(): process 3116 exited                                                             
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944717) sockd[3012]: debug: sigchld(): negotiate-child-child 3116 exiting after 97s and 1 client                       
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944724) sockd[3012]: debug: resource usage for negotiate-child-child 3116                                              
  ru_utime   : 0.000000s                                                                                                                           
  ru_stime   : 0.000000s                                                                                                                           
  ru_minflt  : 197                                                                                                                                 
  ru_majflt  : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nswap   : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_inblock : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_oublock : 16                                                                                                                                  
  ru_msgsnd  : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_msgrcv  : 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nsignals: 0                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nvcsw   : 3                                                                                                                                   
  ru_nivcsw  : 0                                                                                                                                   
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944733) sockd[3012]: debug: removechild(): pid = 3116                                                                  
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944739) sockd[3012]: debug: SIGCHLD ]: finished processing signal 17                                                   
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944744) sockd[3012]: debug: main(): selectn() returned -1 (Interrupted system call)                                    
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944761) sockd[3012]: debug: calling select().  Free negc: 96, reqc: 16, ioc: 32                                        
Feb 17 09:42:01 (1487313721.944782) sockd[3012]: debug: pre-select: nfds = 57, rset = 0x276e630 (7, 10, 18, 20, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, ), bufrset = (nil) (), buffwset = (nil) (), wset =
 (nil) (), xset = (nil) (), timeout = 0x0
```

Trying to downgrade danted server but no luck. Adding rule from:0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0./0 also dont help.

Connetions from server itself also drops with unknown SOCKS error.

Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: same problem here, would you mind share the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

There was provider fault. They inject some additional information that cause this error.